# Implementing a horizontally branching nav menu

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am essentially trying to implement a DOM object that contains many different html templates and can be navigated using different options. I am comfortable with the AngularJS / controller side of this, but unsure about bootstrap and utilizing existing classes/directives.

[image]

My project is currently using angularjs, bootstrap, and angular ui-boostrap. The functionality I  want is pretty similar to ui-bootstrap's accordion functionality but rotated sideways. But all the other options get hidden away when one is selected. Does something like this already exist? Also is there existing code/directive can I use to make the creation of this easier?

I plan for the menu's width and height to be mostly static so my only concern is creating this menu while giving it a clean 'bootstrap' feel.

Answer (score 0):

I think I used this before and was happy with it:

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3

See issue in angular-ui/bootstrap also:

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2421